# FBSDK Login Does not print email

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, fbsdkloginkit

I am implementing the FBSDK Login Button with Firebase and attempted to retrieve email info from the graphRequest but for some reason it does not print the email. Below is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.FBLoginButton.delegate = self
    self.FBLoginButton.readPermissions = ["email"]
    FBSDKProfile.enableUpdates(onAccessTokenChange: true)

}

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        print("User \(user)")

        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email,name"])

        graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err!)
                return
            }

            print(result)

        })

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToFirstView", sender: self)

    }
}
```

The printed results shows this, no email was printed:

```
Optional({
    id = 1233455667;
    name = "the name"; 
})
```

My AppDelegate is as such:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            app,
            open: url as URL!,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        )
    }
```

My intention is to retrieve both name and email to populate my database on Firebase. I adopted most solutions shown on stack overflow but seems like it doesn't quite work for me. Appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you printed the `FBSDKAccessToken.current().permissions` to confirm that it has the right permissions?

Comment: @Andreas I just tried and it prints [AnyHashable("public_profile"), AnyHashable("contact_email"), AnyHashable("email")]. Seems like that it does have the right permissions?